# Capturing a scroll wheel event in MacCatalyst

Tags: mousewheel, mac-catalyst

I have been able to capture the mouse scroll wheel with a UIPanGestureRecognizer.

```
`
    let tPan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.wasPanned))
    tPan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
    tPan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    if #available(macCatalyst 13.4, *) {
        tPan.allowedScrollTypesMask = .discrete
    }
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tPan)

}

@objc func wasPanned(_ pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let thispan = pan
    print(pan)
}

`
```

However, this captures any pan action.   How can I determined if this was a consequence of the mouse scroll wheel?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the event passed to the delegate method `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveEvent:` and only accept the event whose type is `scroll`:

```swift
extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive event: UIEvent) -> Bool {
        event.type == .scroll
    }
}
```

Or you can simply set the property `allowedTouchTypes` to an empty array, which means all touch types are ignored:

```swift
gestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = []
```

Comment: Seems not to work in a mac-catalyst app.   The c responds to touches other that scroll.

Comment: I just tried it and it only responds to the mouse scroll. It doesn't detect pan gestures when I click and move the mouse or using the touchpad.